# Strings being called from dictionaries are invalid syntax? - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

An example:

```
TheDictionary = {
     'Churros' : ['Using','Stack','Overflow']
     'Python' : ['A','Coding','Language']
     }
```

The quotation mark that ends the name 'Python' is apparently invalid syntax. Help?

Comment: You need commas `,` after the dict values

Comment: @snakecharmerb is correct, the error message it tripping up on the 'Python' string because it was not expecting another literal token, it is expecting either a } to close the definition or a ',' to separate the Churros element from the next one. very often when you get errors on a particular line you need to make sure you check the previous statement to see if it it is not complete.

Comment: @Rob I thought I put in the comma after reading this, but apparently I forgot. After inserting the comma, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you a missing a comma. Also in Python, Upper Camel case is reserved for Class names.
Find fixed code below:

```
the_dictionary = {
  'Churros' : ['Using','Stack','Overflow'],
  'Python' : ['A','Coding','Language']
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on the naming issue, it's not invalid syntax (it would work), but it's a commonly accepted naming convention - in particular, see the documentation at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: @saintmarina Thanks! I was never able to respond, but that helped a lot!